# javascript function is executed only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function and I want to call it 12 times. 
So I did like this:

Here I have 12 images:

```
<img id="img1" src=""> </img>
<img id="img2" src=""> </img>
<img id="img3" src=""> </img>
<img id="img4" src=""> </img>
<img id="img5" src=""> </img>
<img id="img6" src=""> </img>
<img id="img7" src=""> </img>
<img id="img8" src=""> </img>
<img id="img9" src=""> </img>
<img id="img10" src=""> </img>
<img id="img11" src=""> </img>
<img id="img12" src=""> </img>
```

Here the function is defined:

```
function addImageSource(id,another_variable) {
      var imageSource = "http://..."+ another_variable + "test";
      $("#img" + id).attr("src", imageSource);
    }
```

And here I call it:

```
          var itm_id = 1;
          while(itm_id < 13){
                  addImageSource(item_id, "another_variable" );
                  itm_id++
            }
```

Why is this function executed only one time? Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: If you call it one time then it would be called for a single time.. No wonder in that..

Comment: Why do you expect it to be called more than once?

Comment: You seem to have mixed `if` and `while`.

Comment: The code you show does not show any kind of loop or anything like that that would call your function more than once.  An `if` statement just executes once.  Did you mean to use a `for` or `while` loop instead?

Comment: Use a loop instead of an IF

Comment: There's a better way of doing this. Use a class selector, iterate, grab the source and call your function with the id. This will allow you to expand beyond hardcoded boundaries

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a for loop so you'll want something like

```
for (var itm_id = 1; itm_id < 13; itm_id++){
    addImageSource(itm_id, "another_variable" );
}
```

Comment: And `itm_id` instead of `item_id` as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the function call inside of a loop. Right now you are using a conditional which is a decision making construct, not a loop.

Replace:

```js
var itm_id = 1;
if (itm_id < 13){
  addImageSource(item_id, "another_variable" );
  itm_id++
}
```

With a for loop like this:

```js
for (var itm_id=1 ; itm_id < 13 ; itm_id++) {
  addImageSource(itm_id, "another_variable" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need for instead of if:

```
  for (var itm_id = 1 ; itm_id < 13; itm_id++) {
         addImageSource(itm_id, "another_variable" );
  }
```

also you made a mistake with this line:

```
addImageSource(item_id, "another_variable" );
```

it should be:

```
addImageSource(itm_id, "another_variable" );
```